# XGBRegressor Pipeline - Error in early_stopping_rounds

Tags: python, scikit-learn, xgboost, preprocessor

I had a previous issue before this, this was fixed. This is the new code.

I am preprocessing a CSV file and I am trying to make n_estimators stop after it has found the best number. you can do this with early_stopping_rounds but it errors when you add this parameter to the preprocessed model.

This is the code:

```
# Preprocessing for numerical data
numerical_transformer = SimpleImputer(strategy='constant')

# Preprocessing for categorical data
categorical_transformer = Pipeline(steps=[
    ('imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy='most_frequent')),
    ('onehot', OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore', dtype=int))
])

from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer

numerical_cols = home_data.select_dtypes(include='number').columns.tolist()
categorical_cols = home_data.select_dtypes(include=['object', 'category']).columns.tolist()

preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(
    transformers=[
        ('num', numerical_transformer, numerical_cols),
        ('cat', categorical_transformer, categorical_cols)
    ])

from xgboost import XGBRegressor

model = XGBRegressor(n_estimators=1000, learning_rate=0.05, n_jobs=4, enable_categorical=True)

my_pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('preprocessor', preprocessor),
    ('model', model)
])

# Fit model and evaluate
my_pipeline.fit(train_X, train_y, model__eval_set=[(val_X, val_y)], model__early_stopping_rounds=5, model__verbose=False)
```

I receive this error

```
ValueError: DataFrame.dtypes for data must be int, float, bool or category. When categorical type is supplied, The experimental DMatrix parameter`enable_categorical` must be set to `True`.  Invalid columns:MSZoning: object, Street: object, Alley: object, LotShape: object, LandContour: object, Utilities: object, LotConfig: object, LandSlope: object, Neighborhood: object, Condition1: object, Condition2: object, BldgType: object, HouseStyle: object, RoofStyle: object, RoofMatl: object, Exterior1st: object, Exterior2nd: object, MasVnrType: object, ExterQual: object, ExterCond: object, Foundation: object, BsmtQual: object, BsmtCond: object, BsmtExposure: object, BsmtFinType1: object, BsmtFinType2: object, Heating: object, HeatingQC: object, CentralAir: object, Electrical: object, KitchenQual: object, Functional: object, FireplaceQu: object, GarageType: object, GarageFinish: object, GarageQual: object, GarageCond: object, PavedDrive: object, PoolQC: object, Fence: object, MiscFeature: object, SaleType: object, SaleCondition: object
```

I think this suggests that my file has objects (non-numerical data) inside of it, despite my doing OneHotEncoding on it.

I then tried out this code instead, where it doesn't find the best n_estimators and it worked so I know the problem is not that.

```
from xgboost import XGBRegressor

model = XGBRegressor(n_estimators=220)

#model = XGBRegressor(n_estimators=1000, learning_rate=0.05, n_jobs=4, enable_categorical=True)


my_pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('preprocessor', preprocessor),
    ('model', model)
])

my_pipeline.fit(train_X, train_y)

#my_pipeline.fit(train_X, train_y, model__eval_set=[(val_X, val_y)], model__early_stopping_rounds=5, model__verbose=False)

preds = my_pipeline.predict(val_X)
score = mean_absolute_error(val_y, preds)
print('MAE:', score)
```

and it worked because it outputted

```
MAE: 1739.843953339041
```

I still want to implement automatically finding n_estimators, what can I do to fix the error?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Ok ill do it, thank you for the help.

Comment: is this any better?

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation you linked, it seems that `enable_categorical` keyword needs to be specified at initialization, so you need to modify the initialization to

```
model = XGBRegressor(n_estimators=1000, learning_rate=0.05, n_jobs=4, enable_categorical=True)
```

and the fit to

```
my_pipeline.fit(train_X, train_y, model__eval_set=[(val_X, val_y)], model__early_stopping_rounds=5, model__verbose=False)
```

Comment: Ah yes, that fixed that line, thanks! but I have another error now, ill update the question.